# How to recover the data that I posted randomly when I click on my profile to redisplay them when I go back php

Tags: recovery

Hello I posted the users randomly on my site but when I click on a user to see his profile I would like when I return I fall back on the same users. PLEASE HELP ME

Comment: You probably want to post some code here, and clarify what you mean by "I posted the users randomly on my site".  I think what you want are some variables to use/pass for the view.  (A "view model")

Comment: No i want retake all infos that i had posted before

Answer (score 0):

// This query will be used to display all users randomly
    $listsAllUsers = $db->prepare("SELECT users1.id, username, sex, country, years, city, 
                                   regionOuProvince, titleOuSlogan, about, 
                                   orientation, looking_for, civil_status, img_original 
                                   FROM users1 
                                   LEFT JOIN users2 ON users1.id = users2.user_id
                                   LEFT JOIN pictures ON users1.id = pictures.user_id
                                   WHERE pictures.active_profile = ?
                                   ORDER BY RAND() $limit");
    $listsAllUsers->execute(['2']);
    $listAllUsers = $listsAllUsers->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php if (is_logged_in()): ?>       
        <?= $verify_email->active == '0' ? '<div class="introduction"><span>Confirm your email : <b>'.$verify_email->email.'</b>, Otherwise your account will be disabled after 30 days.</span></div>' : '' ?>      
    <?php endif ?>

<?php include_once 'partials/searching.php'; ?>

<!-- CATEGORIES_INFOS -->
<div class="header_bar_djaspora" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    Members connected for meeting
</div>

<div class="introduction">
    <div id="standardProfileViewProfile">
        <?php if (is_logged_in()): ?>
            <?php if ($data->display_user_fetch == '1'): ?>
                <u><a href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>/?action=standard_profile">Use standard profile view</a></u>         
            <?php else: ?>
                <u><a href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>">View profiles by thumbnail</a></u>
            <?php endif ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php if ($action): ?>
                <u><a href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>">View profiles by thumbnail</a></u>
            <?php else: ?>
                <u><a href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>/?action=standard_profile">Use standard profile view</a></u>
            <?php endif ?>
        <?php endif ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php if (is_logged_in()): ?>
    <?php if ($data->display_user_fetch == '1'): ?>
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="usersFetch">
                <center>
                    <?php if (count($listAllUsers) != 0): ?>
                        <?php foreach ($listAllUsers as $listAllUser): ?>
                            <li style="text-align:center;">
                                <div class="userFetchBloc">
                                    <a href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>/profile/<?= strtolower($listAllUser->username) ?>">
                                        <img src="/<?= $listAllUser->img_original ?>" class="img_user_fetch_bloc" style="width: 100%;" alt="Meeting <?= $listAllUser->username ?> On <?= WEBSITE_NAME ?>">
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="fetchInfosUserStandardProfile">
                                        <span class="fetchInfosUserText">
                                            &nbsp;<span class="infosUserText2"><?= $listAllUser->username ?>, </span><?= date('Y') - $listAllUser->years ?> old&nbsp;<br>
                                            &nbsp;<?= $listAllUser->city ?><span class="infosUserText">, <?= $listAllUser->regionOuProvince ?></span>&nbsp;
                                            <span class="infosUserText2"><br>&nbsp;<?= NbrePictures($listAllUser->id) ?> photo<?= NbrePictures($listAllUser->id) > 1 ? 's' : ''; ?>&nbsp;</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="all_necessary_infos">
                                    <div>
                                        <b><?= $listAllUser->titleOuSlogan ?></b>
                                    </div>
                                    <em><?= $listAllUser->civil_status ?> <?= $listAllUser->sex ?> of <?= date('Y') - $listAllUser->years ?> years looking for <?= verify_looking_for($listAllUser->id, $listAllUser->sex) ?> for <?= $listAllUser->orientation ?></em>
                                    <div class="wideDiv">
                                        <?= $listAllUser->about ?>
                                    </div>
                                        <strong>Meet</strong> <a style="color: #be0210;" href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>/meet-<?= lcfirst($listAllUser->sex) ?>-<?= suppr_accents($listAllUser->city) ?>" style="color:#be0210;"><?= $listAllUser->city ?></a>, 
                                            <a style="color: #be0210;" href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>/meet-<?= lcfirst($listAllUser->sex) ?>-<?= suppr_accents($listAllUser->regionOuProvince) ?>" style="color:#be0210;"><?= $listAllUser->regionOuProvince ?></a>, 
                                            <a style="color: #be0210;" href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>/meet-<?= lcfirst($listAllUser->sex) ?>-<?= lcfirst($listAllUser->country) ?>" style="color:#be0210;"><?= $listAllUser->country ?></a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p style="text-align: center;">No users on <?= WEBSITE_NAME ?></p>
                    <?php endif ?>
                </center>
            </ul>
            <?php if (count($listAllUsers) != 0): ?>
                <div id="pagination" style="position: relative; top: 10px; bottom: 5px;"><?= $pagination ?></div>
            <?php endif ?>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php if (count($listAllUsers) != 0): ?>
            <?php foreach ($listAllUsers as $key => $listAllUser): ?>
                <div id="user_container_testimony">
                    <div class="userTestimony">
                        <span class="img_message_testimony">
                            <a href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>/profile/<?= strtolower($listAllUser->username) ?>">
                                <img src="/<?= $listAllUser->img_original ?>" class="img_testimony" alt="This image shows <?= $listAllUser->username ?> meeting on <?= WEBSITE_NAME ?>.">
                            </a>
                        </span>
                        <div class="fetchInfosUserStandardProfileStyle">
                            <span class="fetchInfosUserText">
                                &nbsp;<span class="infosUserText2"><?= $listAllUser->username ?>, </span><?= date('Y') - $listAllUser->years ?> old&nbsp;<br>
                                &nbsp;<?= $listAllUser->city ?><span class="infosUserText">, <?= $listAllUser->regionOuProvince ?></span>&nbsp;
                                <span class="infosUserText2"><br>&nbsp;<?= NbrePictures($listAllUser->id) ?> photo<?= (NbrePictures($listAllUser->id) > 1) ? 's' : '' ?>&nbsp;</span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="allTestimony">
                            <div class="titleTestimony">
                                <strong><u><?= $listAllUser->titleOuSlogan ?></u></strong> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="subtitleTestimony">
                                <span class="describeSubtitleTestimony">
                                    <u><a href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>/profile/<?= strtolower($listAllUser->username) ?>" style="color: #be0210;"><?= $listAllUser->username ?></a></u> <?= $listAllUser->civil_status ?> <?= $listAllUser->sex ?> of <?= date('Y') - $listAllUser->years ?> years looking for <?= verify_looking_for($listAllUser->id, $listAllUser->sex) ?> for <?= $listAllUser->orientation ?>
                                </span> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="testimony">
                                <span class="describeTestimony">
                                    <?= mb_strlen($listAllUser->about) > 350 ? substr($listAllUser->about, 0, 350).' <a href="'.WEBSITE_NAME_URL.'/profile/'.strtolower($listAllUser->username).'" style="color: #be0210;">More Read...</a>' : $listAllUser->about ?>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="meetCityRegion">
                            <strong>Meet</strong> <u style="color: #be0210;"><a href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>/meet-<?= lcfirst($listAllUser->sex) ?>-<?= suppr_accents($listAllUser->city) ?>" style="color:#be0210;"><?= $listAllUser->city ?></a></u>, 
                                <u style="color: #be0210;"><a href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>/meet-<?= lcfirst($listAllUser->sex) ?>-<?= suppr_accents($listAllUser->regionOuProvince) ?>" style="color:#be0210;"><?= $listAllUser->regionOuProvince ?></a></u>, 
                                <u style="color: #be0210;"><a href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>/meet-<?= lcfirst($listAllUser->sex) ?>-<?= lcfirst($listAllUser->country) ?>" style="color:#be0210;"><?= $listAllUser->country ?></a></u>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            <div id="pagination" style="position: relative; top: 10px; bottom: 5px;"><?= $pagination ?></div>
        <?php else: ?>
            <p style="text-align: center;">You have not traded anything with this user yet.</p>
        <?php endif ?>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php if (!$action): ?>
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="usersFetch">
                <center>
                    <?php if (count($listAllUsers) != 0): ?>
                        <?php foreach ($listAllUsers as $listAllUser): ?>
                            <li style="text-align:center;">
                                <div class="userFetchBloc">
                                    <a href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>/profile/<?= strtolower($listAllUser->username) ?>">
                                        <img src="/<?= $listAllUser->img_original ?>" class="img_user_fetch_bloc" style="width: 100%;" alt="Meeting <?= $listAllUser->username ?> On <?= WEBSITE_NAME ?>">
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="fetchInfosUserStandardProfile">
                                        <span class="fetchInfosUserText">
                                            &nbsp;<span class="infosUserText2"><?= $listAllUser->username ?>, </span><?= date('Y') - $listAllUser->years ?> old&nbsp;<br>
                                            &nbsp;<?= $listAllUser->city ?><span class="infosUserText">, <?= $listAllUser->regionOuProvince ?></span>&nbsp;
                                            <span class="infosUserText2"><br>&nbsp;<?= NbrePictures($listAllUser->id) ?> photo<?= (NbrePictures($listAllUser->id) > 1) ? 's' : '' ?>&nbsp;</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="all_necessary_infos">
                                    <div>
                                        <b><?= $listAllUser->titleOuSlogan ?></b>
                                    </div>
                                    <em><?= $listAllUser->civil_status ?> <?= $listAllUser->sex ?> of <?= date('Y') - $listAllUser->years ?> years looking for <?= verify_looking_for($listAllUser->id, $listAllUser->sex) ?> for <?= $listAllUser->orientation ?></em>
                                    <div class="wideDiv">
                                        <?= $listAllUser->about ?>
                                    </div>
                                        <strong>Meet</strong> <a style="color: #be0210;" href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>/meet-<?= lcfirst($listAllUser->sex) ?>-<?= suppr_accents($listAllUser->city) ?>" style="color:#be0210;"><?= $listAllUser->city ?></a>, 
                                            <a style="color: #be0210;" href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>/meet-<?= lcfirst($listAllUser->sex) ?>-<?= suppr_accents($listAllUser->regionOuProvince) ?>" style="color:#be0210;"><?= $listAllUser->regionOuProvince ?></a>, 
                                            <a style="color: #be0210;" href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>/meet-<?= lcfirst($listAllUser->sex) ?>-<?= lcfirst($listAllUser->country) ?>" style="color:#be0210;"><?= $listAllUser->country ?></a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p style="text-align: center;">No users on <?= WEBSITE_NAME ?></p>
                    <?php endif ?>
                </center>
            </ul>
            <?php if (count($listAllUsers) != 0): ?>
                <div id="pagination" style="position: relative; top: 10px; bottom: 5px;"><?= $pagination ?></div>
            <?php endif ?>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php if (count($listAllUsers) != 0): ?>
            <?php foreach ($listAllUsers as $listAllUser):?>
                <div id="user_container_testimony">
                    <div class="userTestimony">
                        <span class="img_message_testimony">
                            <a href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>/profile/<?= strtolower($listAllUser->username) ?>">
                                <img src="/<?= $listAllUser->img_original ?>" class="img_testimony" alt="This image shows <?= $listAllUser->username ?> meeting on <?= WEBSITE_NAME ?>.">
                            </a>
                        </span>
                        <div class="fetchInfosUserStandardProfileStyle">
                            <span class="fetchInfosUserText">
                                &nbsp;<span class="infosUserText2"><?= $listAllUser->username ?>, </span><?= date('Y') - $listAllUser->years ?> old&nbsp;<br>
                                &nbsp;<?= $listAllUser->city ?><span class="infosUserText">, <?= $listAllUser->regionOuProvince ?></span>&nbsp;
                                <span class="infosUserText2"><br>&nbsp;<?= NbrePictures($listAllUser->id) ?> photo<?= (NbrePictures($listAllUser->id) > 1) ? 's' : '' ?>&nbsp;</span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="allTestimony">
                            <div class="titleTestimony">
                                <strong><u><?= $listAllUser->titleOuSlogan ?></u></strong> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="subtitleTestimony">
                                <span class="describeSubtitleTestimony">
                                    <u><a href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>/profile/<?= strtolower($listAllUser->username) ?>" style="color: #be0210;"><?= $listAllUser->username ?></a></u> <?= $listAllUser->civil_status ?> <?= $listAllUser->sex ?> of <?= date('Y') - $listAllUser->years ?> years looking for <?= verify_looking_for($listAllUser->id, $listAllUser->sex) ?> for <?= $listAllUser->orientation ?>
                                </span> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="testimony">
                                <span class="describeTestimony">
                                    <?= mb_strlen($listAllUser->about) > 350 ? substr($listAllUser->about, 0, 350).' <a href="'.WEBSITE_NAME_URL.'/profile/'.strtolower($listAllUser->username).'" style="color: #be0210;">More Read...</a>' : $listAllUser->about ?>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="meetCityRegion">
                            <strong>Meet</strong> <u style="color: #be0210;"><a href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>/meet-<?= lcfirst($listAllUser->sex) ?>-<?= suppr_accents($listAllUser->city) ?>" style="color:#be0210;"><?= $listAllUser->city ?></a></u>, 
                                <u style="color: #be0210;"><a href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>/meet-<?= lcfirst($listAllUser->sex) ?>-<?= suppr_accents($listAllUser->regionOuProvince) ?>" style="color:#be0210;"><?= $listAllUser->regionOuProvince ?></a></u>, 
                                <u style="color: #be0210;"><a href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>/meet-<?= lcfirst($listAllUser->sex) ?>-<?= lcfirst($listAllUser->country) ?>" style="color:#be0210;"><?= $listAllUser->country ?></a></u>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            <div id="pagination" style="position: relative; top: 10px; bottom: 5px;"><?= $pagination ?></div>
        <?php else: ?>
            <p style="text-align: center;">You have not traded anything with this user yet.</p>
        <?php endif ?>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php endif ?>

<script>
    if ($('.introduction #alert_message').val()) {
       $(".introduction span").css("display", "none")
    }
</script>
<?php require_once 'partials/footer.php'; ?>
```